# Bookmarks for favourite questions in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I'd like to have the ability to bookmark questions I'm interested in.

Comment: Have you seen the stars underneath the questions?

Comment: @Mithrandir Ah, sorry, really. I noticed not the elephant at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android app already has this - tap the "Favorite" button underneath the question you want to favorite:

[image: Android: Favorite Option]

To view your favorite questions list, you can search for "`infavorites:mine`", both in the Android app or on the desktop site, or you can visit the [favorites tab of your profile](/users/current?tab=favorites) on the site.